# Matrix-loop within another matrix-loop

Tags: matrix

i'm quite new to ExpressionEngine so please forgive me if this is a stupid/badly formed question, but i could really use some help on this one.

So my problem is that within my template i have a matrix-loop, and within that loop i have another matrix loop, which depends on the value of the outer loop.

Here's how i would like it to work:

```
{outer_matrix_field var_prefix="outer"}
    {another_matrix_field var_prefix="inner"}
        {if inner:package_{outer:row_count} == "y"}
            .. do stuff in here ..
        {/if}
    {/another_matrix_field}
{/outer_matrix_field}
```

The `inner:package_{outer:row_count}` gets parsed to `inner:package_1`, but that in turn is not parsed into its value.

It seems to me like it is some problem with the order of how EE parses/executes the tags, and i've tried with parse="inward" everywhere and that seems to do nothing.

Now i know that this could probably be solved using something like Playa, but that is not an option as the client has specifically asked for this solution.

So, what i need to know is if this is even possible.

Thank you

Comment: I solved it myself, using embeds, and passing the {row_count} as a variable. That made it parse things in the right order. So essentially what i did in the first place, only i broke out the inner loop to an embed. I also discovered the greatness of the matrix "search" option, but that's a whole other story.

Answer (score 2):

Like you mentioned in your comment, embeds should do the trick, but be aware embeds are very costly to performance. If you have a big loop, and subsequently many embeds, you could see a rather significant performance decrease.

Instead of your normal embeds, you can also try using stash embeds. https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bstash%3Aembed%7D

Also, take a look into ce caching to see if you can avoid having to run the potentially costly loop each page load. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-cache

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I will definitely look into stash embeds and ce caching. I thought maybe the built in ExpressionEngine-cache could also do the trick, as this content is not likely to change once an entry has been finalized.

Comment: Also, i would upvote your answer if i had the reputation to do so.

Comment: Yeah normal EE caching could do the trick too